# Inserting across several tables using joins and junction table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

I do apologize, I know this question pops up a lot, but I'm afraid I just don't understand the answers I've read on the subject and was hoping someone could clear things up for me.

I have three tables:

`Recipes (ID int primary identity, RecipeName varchar(20), Directions varchar(max), RecIngID int)`

`Ingredients (ID int primary identity, IngredientName varchar(30), Quantity int)`

and a junction table, `Recipe_Ingredients (RecipeID int foreign key references Recipe(ID), IngredientID int foreign key references Ingredient(ID)`

Now, that being said, I need to create stored procedures for everything (because I'm creating an ntier program using asp.net MVC 4 and C#, blah blah blah....

But I have no clue how to write a stored procedure for inserting a new recipe into that table, and taking into account the relationship between the junction table `Recipe_Ingredients` and the `Ingredient` table.

Can someone please, PLEASE help me here?  All the explanations I've read haven't really made sense.  If there's something I'm doing wrong, please tell me.

Comment: You'll have to insert the ingredient and recipe and save each id in a temp variable. Then insert both ids in your recipe_ingredients table.

Comment: Because you want everything done in a SP you will probably have better luck checking data administrators stackexchange. See this previous answer: [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each ingredient call this stored procedure

```
create procedure insertIngredients
(
    @name varchar,
    @quantity int
)
as
insert into Ingredients (IngredientName, Quantity)
values (@name, @quantity)

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

which inserts ingredient and returns it's newly inserted ID.
Store that ids into some variable (ie, List or comma delimited string).
After that, insert recipe calling procedure:

```
create procedure insertRecipe
(
    @name varchar,
    @directions varchar(max),
    @RecIngID int
)
as
insert into Recipes (RecipeName, Directions, RecIngID)
values (@name, @directions, @RecIngID)

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

also save ID which that procedure returns after insert.
And, as last step insert data into junction table using recipe ID and all those Ingredient ID's you previously inserted.

```
create procedure insertRecipeIngredients
(
    @recipeID int,
    @ingredientID int
)
as
insert into Recipe_Ingredients (RecipeID, IngredientID)
values (@recipeID, @ingredientID)

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

in your c# code call procedures like this:

```
public int InsertIngredient(string name, int quantity)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("[your connection string goes here]");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "insertIngredients";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity);

    conn.Open();

    int newlyInsertedId = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
    conn.Close();

    return newlyInsertedId;
}
```

Comment: This clears a lot of things up for me, thank you so much!  The only question I have left, then, is how would the SP store that variable to be spat back out for the next SP that's needed?  Especially when I get up into the DAL and BLL in the program itself?  

I do apologize if I'm missing the forest for the trees here, but we only spent about 4 days learning SQL. :(

Comment: @SnarkyBird, check out edited answer, I added c# example. And, if it helped you, mark as answer ;)

Comment: Marked as answered, because it helped greatly!  Much appreciated!